# ROR: i18n best practices for large translation dictionaries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dictionary, internationalization, translation

- When internationalizing a rails app, what is the best practice way for organizing/scoping translations in the dictionary files?
- Under what circumstance should you use interpolations of variables?
- Should every phrase be it's entry?
- Is there anyone who participated in dhh's tolk who can shed some light on how 37signals broke up their dictionary files?

After a month and a half of using the i18n gem our en.yml file is becoming gigantic. Is there any benefit to using scoping? We want the dictionary to be easier to translate and to keep our dictionary DRY but want to take into consideration different tenses and still take advantage of situations where we have *"Are you sure you want to delete this object?"*, *"Are you sure you want to mark this as completed?"* As *"Are you sure you want to {{verb}} this {{noun}}?"*

Comment: I retitled again and reformatted, hope you don't mind.

Comment: I totally don't! Thanks oodles. I'm still an Overflow noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, on our organization we completelly translated it with the default directory structures suggested by Rails

we have our locale and then we have either views or models
for every view and model we created the translations and it works perfectly.

for instance, in a HomeController#show we use:

```
t('.title')
```

and it looks in the views/home/{locale}.yml for the

```
{locale}:
  show:
    title:
```

It also works well with partials.
Same example as above, but in a 'latest' partial would be

```
{locale}:
  latest:
    title:
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for, but hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problems year ago, as the result I've built [t_t gem](https://github.com/jalkoby/tt). It dramatically reduces amount of duplications in translation files. For more details look at [cheatsheet](https://github.com/jalkoby/tt/blob/master/cheatsheet.md) - section `# Actions` will help you with "Are you sure you want to {{verb}} this {{noun}}?"

UPDATED:

[an example gist](https://gist.github.com/jalkoby/7a29b2dfb325db7ff052)

Comment: If you're going to post a "use my library" answer, your answer should explain _how to use your library_, not just a link.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11274593)

Comment: I've created a gist which shows how the library deals with this case https://gist.github.com/jalkoby/7a29b2dfb325db7ff052